# How to get value in a fragment method from OkHttp3 response callback interface

Tags: android, android-fragments, okhttp

Here is my Singleton class where I've implemented the OkHttp post request. In the post request I've used a callback interface so that I can get response value in my fragment from where I've called the post request.I wish to call a fragments method from the interface's call back response.

Singleton class:

```
package com.retailreadyonline.retailreadyonline.utils;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.FormBody;
import okhttp3.HttpUrl;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton INSTANCE = null;
    private Singleton() {};

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new Singleton();
        }
        return(INSTANCE);
    }

    public void doPostRequest(String url, List<DataPair> dataPairs, final HttpResponseCallBack responseCallBack) throws IOException {
        MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM);

        for (DataPair dataPair:dataPairs) {
            builder.addFormDataPart(dataPair.getKey(),dataPair.getValue());
        }
        MultipartBody requestBody = builder.build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                String strResponse = response.body().string();
                try {
                    responseCallBack.getResponse(strResponse);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my call back interface

```
package com.retailreadyonline.retailreadyonline.utils;

public interface HttpResponseCallBack {
    void getResponse(String response);
}
```

And the fragment where I've called the doPostRequest.

```
package com.retailreadyonline.retailreadyonline.fragments;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.retailreadyonline.retailreadyonline.R;
import com.retailreadyonline.retailreadyonline.utils.Car;
import com.retailreadyonline.retailreadyonline.utils.CarListAdapter;
import com.retailreadyonline.retailreadyonline.utils.DataPair;
import com.retailreadyonline.retailreadyonline.utils.HttpResponseCallBack;
import com.retailreadyonline.retailreadyonline.utils.Singleton;
import com.retailreadyonline.retailreadyonline.utils.StaticValues;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CarListFragment extends Fragment{
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    List<Car> carList;
    ListView lvCars;
    private static CarListAdapter carListAdapter;
    List<DataPair> dataPairs;

    public CarListFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static CarListFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        CarListFragment fragment = new CarListFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
        dataPairs = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View fragView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_car_list, container, false);
        lvCars = (ListView) fragView.findViewById(R.id.lvCars);

        DataPair objDataPair = new DataPair();
        objDataPair.setKey("user_id");
        objDataPair.setValue("1");
        dataPairs.add(objDataPair);

        if(carListAdapter != null) {
            carListAdapter.clear();
        }
        try {
            Singleton.getInstance().doPostRequest(StaticValues.getDetailsByVin, dataPairs, new HttpResponseCallBack() {
                @Override
                public void getResponse(String response) {
                    Log.i("POSTRESPONSE", response);
                    parseJsonResponse(response);                    
                }
            });
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return fragView;
    }

    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    public void parseJsonResponse(String message){

    }
}
```

I wish to call the parseJsonResponse method from the HttpResponseCallBack()'s getResponse method. How can I do so? Or is there any other alternative to get response other than callback interface?

Comment: you got error ?

Comment: No, I'm not getting error. I can see the response in the log but I wish to process to response that's why wish to call a fragment method. Like here I called parseJsonResponse(response); I see that method never called!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                  parseJsonResponse(response);

                                    }


                                }
                            });
```

Try put parseJsonResponse(response); in this thread .. I think laa ..

Comment: Great! It's working. I've tried in the following way but found it's not allowed to call UI thread on fragment.

CarListFragment.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            
                        }
                    });